# Crear una matriz de matrices en python

Tags: python

estimados, tengo una consulta, ¿como puedo hacer un tablero o matriz de matrices en Python?, considerando que la matriz que va a formar mi tablero o matriz mayor es una clase (tiene los tributos de poder girar y rellenar datos dentro de esa misma matriz)

```
class matriz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = [[0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0]]
    def __str__(self):
        txt =""
        txt +=str(self.t[0][0])+str(self.t[0][1])+str(self.t[0][2])+"\n"
        txt +=str(self.t[1][0])+str(self.t[1][1])+str(self.t[1][2])+"\n"
        txt +=str(self.t[2][0])+str(self.t[2][1])+str(self.t[2][2])
        return txt 
    def casilla_vacia(self, f, c):
        libre=self.t[f][c]==0
        return libre 
    def rellenar_casilla(self,f,c,j):
        libre=self.casilla_vacia(f,c)
        if libre:
            self.t[f][c]=j
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def nada_libre(self):
        ocupado= ((not 0 in self.t[0]) and 
                  (not 0 in self.t[1]) and
                  (not 0 in self.t[2]))
        return ocupado 
    def girar_izquierda(self):
        new_m = [[0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0]]
        new_m[0][0]=self.t[0][2]
        new_m[1][0]=self.t[0][1]
        new_m[2][0]=self.t[0][0]
        new_m[0][1]=self.t[1][2]
        new_m[2][1]=self.t[1][0]
        new_m[0][2]=self.t[2][2]
        new_m[1][2]=self.t[2][1]
        new_m[2][2]=self.t[2][0]

        print(self) 
    def girar_derecha(self):
        new_ma = [[0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0]]
        new_ma[0][0]=self.t[2][0]
        new_ma[1][0]=self.t[2][1]
        new_ma[2][0]=self.t[2][2]
        new_ma[0][1]=self.t[1][0]
        new_ma[2][1]=self.t[1][2]
        new_ma[0][2]=self.t[0][0]
        new_ma[1][2]=self.t[0][1]
        new_ma[2][2]=self.t[0][2]

        print(self) 

tab= matriz()
```

basicamente quiero hacer una matriz, pero en la que cada elemento de esa matriz sea una matriz de 3X3 que esta definida en el código de arriba

Comment: Deberias ampliar tu pregunta con más información, ¿a que te refieres con matriz de matrices? 
Dices que tu matriz es una clase, ¿como está implementada esa clase?, aportar el código a ser posible. Eplicar claramente o con algún ejemplo lo que desesas y el problema concreto que se te presenta seria de gran ayuda. Saludos

Comment: no es clara tu pregunta..  corrigue por favor

Comment: ya lo corregí, espero que se entienda mejor, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

necesitas hacer una lista de listas de objetos:

```
array =[]
for count in range(3):
   row=[]
   for count in range(3):
     m = matriz()     
     row.append(m)
   array.append(row)
```

también puedes obtenerlo con un List Comprehensions:

```
comparray=[[matriz() for x in range(3)] for r in range(3)]
```

si quieres obtener el array de tu clase tienes que agregar un getter en tu clase
por ejemplo:

```
def getArray(self):
   return self.t
```

luego puedes obtener imprimirlos con una lista como esta

```
imparray=[[comparray[x][y].getArray() for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]

[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]], [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

para que se vea mejor puedes usar un pprint

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(imparray)
[[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],
 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]]
```

Comment: pero como lo hago para que salga como matriz y no como esto                    [ [<__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>], [<__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>], [<__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>, <__main__.matriz instance at 0x111cf7878>]]

Comment: necesitas agregarle un getter a tu clase, uno mejor que este, comparray[0][0].__str__()

Comment: @VICENTEDANIELPALACIOS actualice la respuesta para obtener lo que pides.

Comment: estimado Jorge, muchas gracias

Comment: @VICENTEDANIELPALACIOS si la respuesta solucionó tu problema considera [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) para demostrar la utilidad de esta a otros usuarios y reconocer el esfurzo del autor. Saludos.